# setTitle of UITabBarController crashed in iOS 5 for more than 5 items?

Tags: xcode4, uitabbarcontroller, ios5

Before updating my Xcode from 4.1 to 4.2 the following was code was working fine with iOS 4.3, but after upgrading Xcode and test my app on iPhone with iOS 5 it keep crashing on startup!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[self.window addSubview:tabController.view];
[[tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"Tab1"];
[[tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"Tab2"];
[[tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"Tab3"];
[[tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setTitle:@"Tab4"];
[[tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4] setTitle:@"Tab5"];
[[tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:5] setTitle:@"Tab6"];
[[tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:6] setTitle:@"Tab7"];
[[tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:7] setTitle:@"Tab8"];
[[tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:8] setTitle:@"Tab9"];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

It throws the following error:

```
2011-10-15 15:13:31.238 Mobile[2347:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x311138bf 0x382b81e5 0x3106b275 0x336b 0x330e57eb 0x330df3bd 0x330ad921 0x330ad3bf 0x330acd2d 0x33c98e13 0x310e7553 0x310e74f5 0x310e6343 0x310694dd 0x310693a5 0x330de457 0x330db743 0x2acd 0x2a28)
```

If I kept only the first 5 setTitle it will work, but if its more than 5 it will crash!

Please note that I'm creating the UITabBarController in IB not programatically.

Comment: What is the deal with the , nil) ... I don't see where you open that with anything?

Comment: Sorry, I took out the NSLocalizedString("Tab1",nil), so I forgot to remove the nil :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing the viewControllers array on the tabController instead and editing the tabItem on the View Controller directly.

```
[[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0].tabBarItem setTitle:@"Tab1"];
```

Comment: This is just a guess, because I don't see it listed anywhere in the docs, but I would think that since you can only display 5 items at a time, tabController.tabBar.items may now be bound to only 5 items, and in iOS 4 it wasn't.

Comment: You're genius :) But there's a little correction: [[[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]tabBarItem]setTitle:@"Tab1"]